# Insert more than one row material table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-table

I am trying to add more than one row into a mat table so i have a field where the user introduce a number for example: "2"

then i ask if he wants to introduce it as one row or separately if everything is in one row its fine but when i try to add separately
it breaks and only introduce one row instead of number written

then loop for and `setData()` inside the for

```js
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const json = {
    id: id,
    name: null,
};

const newArr3 = [];
for (let index = 0; index < number; index++) {
    newArr3.push(json);
    postRequest(json);
    setData(newArr3);
}

<MaterialTable
    columns={columns}
    data={data}
    title="Table 2"
    options={{
        exportButton: true,
        filtering: true,
        actionsColumnIndex: -1,
        headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#01579b',
            color: '#FFF'
        },
        rowStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#EEEEEE',
        }
    }}
/>
```

I saw by components react tools developer that it introduces 2 objects inside the array `data` but only display one, maybe because it has the same `tabledata {id:0}` when it would be: `tabledata {id:0}` and `tabledata {id:1}` but i don't know how to do it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The problem might be, that you push the exact json object as reference into your array. So mainly you add `number` times the exact same object. To change the id while also pushing a copy into the array you might try: `newArr3.push({...json, id: index})`

Comment: what is the value of `number`? there is a possibility, that you are actually just adding the data once. Also columns is unkown, the logic looks ok, but first log data and ensure it has morethan a single item

Comment: @IsaacSekamatte number = 2 then it adds only one line, one row i mean

Comment: @TimDithmer i've already tried destructuring it and even adding newArr3.push({...json, tableData:{id:index}}) and it still displays only one row [screenshot](https://gyazo.com/9d4468d417b72df789f8bcb11831dc07)

Comment: `newArr3.push({...json, tableData:{id:index}})` would create an object looking like this: `{id: id, name: null, tableData: {id: 1}}` for `index = 1`. Have you tried it exactly like I wrote it?

Comment: @TimDithmer Yes, it introduces into the array: {"tableData":{"id":1}, name: null, "id":1} But it only show in the table one row. If i close the modal without refreshing (F5) and I open it again as it is saved in a state it shows 2 rows, but not at the beginning. [screenshot 1 table displaying one row](https://gyazo.com/a7747958f48ce057101cd364d1ead4c3) [screenshot 2 array info](https://gyazo.com/9d4468d417b72df789f8bcb11831dc07)

Answer (score 1):

Try ty give `index` of `for` loop as `id`.

```js
const newArr3 = [];
for (let index = 0; index < number; index++) {
    const json = {
        id: index,
        name: null
    }
    newArr3.push(json);
    postRequest(json);
    setData(newArr3);
}
```

Comment: [screenshot 1 table displaying one row](https://gyazo.com/a7747958f48ce057101cd364d1ead4c3) [screenshot 2 array info](https://gyazo.com/9d4468d417b72df789f8bcb11831dc07)

Comment: If i close the modal without refreshing (F5) and I open it again as it is saved in a state it shows 2 rows, but not at the beginning